# Is there an easier way to add controls into R regression (in STATA we use global) without having to copy and paste all controls for every regression?

Tags: r, regression, lm

Suppose I run several regressions but with all the same controls and different variables of interest. It would be nice to specify a list of controls that I could add to the regression without having to type out every control.

In STATA we can simply type  `global controls y z` and then include

```
reg dep $controls
```

In R I was hoping it would be something as such

```
controls <- "log(mkt) + mb + lt + ni"
model <- lm(dep ~ indep + controls, data=df)
summary(model)
```

This does not seem to work and haven't been able to find another way. Do not feel like moving back to STATA for this project just so that I can have a neater looking code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `reformulate`. Here is a reproducible example using the `mtcars` dataset.

```r
controls <- c("disp", "drat")
model <- lm(reformulate(c("wt", controls), response = "mpg"), data = mtcars)
```

The key is to provide `controls` as a `character` vector of your (log-transformed) control variables.

---

So in your case:

```r
controls <- c("log(mkt)", "mb", "lt", "ni")
model <- lm(reformulate(c("indep", controls), response = "dep"), data = df)
summary(model)
```